Cannot Use RecyclerView in .NET Android MAUI
With the ended support of Xamarin, I am working on converting my Xamarin.Android app to .NET Android MAUI (my app is Android only). In my xml layout file(s), I am able to use androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView without any complaints from Visual Studio 2022, but in my *.cs file(s), I am unable to use RecyclerView or any related classes. If I add the following using statement:
using AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;
Visual Studio 2022 give the following error:
The type or namespace name 'RecyclerView' does not exist in the namespace 'AndroidX' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Intellisense suggests that I install the package Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView, but the goal is to NOT use Xamarin, so I know this is not the correct solution. What am I forgetting or what do I need to do in order to use RecyclerView in .NET Android MAUI?

see the sample code here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21895

RecylerView in MAUI? Do you mean CollectionView?

I do not mean CollectionView, I do mean RecyclerView. I am using .NET Android MAUI, not MAUI that will be used for all platforms. When I looked at the link provided, it uses
using AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;
Which, as I said in my original post, gives an error. Is there something in the link you provide that I am missing?

See the answer to your question on the MS Forum. The correct term for an Android-only app is .NET for Android. It is not .Net Android Maui. You should remove the Maui tag in your questions. You are also confusing others with their answers

Sorry about that (I am new to .NET for Android), I will remove the Maui tag, but it still doesn't answer my question.
